# How can I navigate to individual windows?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have many many apps running in the background some are infact two or three windows of same program, i.e. Firefox 3-4 windows and Xcode 3-4 windows etc...

I know that I can switch using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> but that only switches on programs and I want to go to each individual window.

I've tried spotlight and it's not what im looking for. Also, I do not prefer to install any paid software and would like to use build in features if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To switch between windows of the same application, use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>.

If you need a shortcut like the Windows' <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> that switches between all open windows, you can set one in your System Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts as shown below.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

As you can see above, the default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, which actually means you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> because of the special meaning of the function keys. You could change it to any unused key combination, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> itself.

Comment: cool didnt knew things like this exist in mac appreciate it -- any other cool things i can capture as a mac newbie?

Comment: @codejunkie: Definitely! Look up the [most upvoted questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) on this site.

Comment: out interest how do you do page up and page down in a document i.e.if i press ctrl page up in eclipse it goes top of page and if i press ctrl page down it goes last line on page.

Comment: @codejunkie: I'm not sure which shortcuts you're referring to, but the equivalent of the Windows' PageUp/Down is Fn+Up/Down Arrow. The equivalent of Home/End is Fn+Left/Right Arrow.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to navigate between windows build right into OSX.
Basic input methods are...

### **[Shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343)**

You can configure various window management effects in
   **System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Mission Control/Keyboard & Text Input**

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>+(<kbd>⇧</kbd>) Application Switcher
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>+(<kbd>⇧</kbd>) Window Switcher
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>  Desktop Switcher
- some of the function keys trigger certain features
- ...

### **[Gestures](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4721)**

You can configure various window management effects in **System Prefernces → Trackpad/Mouse** (requires multitouch input device)

Using these inputs you can trigger the following window management options...

1. ### [Classical Exposé](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2503)

   (OSX 10.3-10.6)
   View all open windows of all open applications at once.

   [image]
2. ### Dock/App Exposé

   (like 1, but only of one application) (OSX 10.6-today)
3. ### [Mission Control](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4689) (OSX 10.7-today)

   View all open windows of all open applications and all desktops at once.

   [image]